# Use values of object as a type - $Values - similar to $Keys

Tags: flowtype

From the flow docs we have this:

```
// @flow
const countries = {
  US: "United States",
  IT: "Italy",
  FR: "France"
};

type Country = $Keys<typeof countries>;

const italy: Country = 'IT';
const nope: Country = 'nope'; // 'nope' is not a Country
```

However I want to do

```
type CountryValue = $Values<typeof countries>
const italy: CountryValue = 'Italy'; // yes
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sorta use `$Values`, although you also need to do a little more, as currently the values inside `countries` are just detected as being any `string`. If you tell flow that only certain values are allowed, then it works:

```
type FullNames = "United States" | "Italy";

const countries: {[key: string]: FullNames} = {
  US: "United States",
  IT: "Italy"
};


const nope: $Values(typeof countries) = 'nope'; // 'nope' is not in the value type
```

I would guess this isn't *quite* what you want, since it requires adding the type explicitly, but it is doable.

Comment: Ah darn, thanks for that, it seems I have to define the `type FullNames` enum anyways so might as well use that huh?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it won't infer the enum type from the values of the object literal. Which sorta makes sense, since most of the type that you have an object literal, you don't want to limit it to the initial values.

Comment: Thank you for your help very much, I Have accepted this because at least it works and conveys the message that it should be a value in that object and ensure that values in that object are from the given :)

Comment: This answer was closer to what I was looking for: using `Object.freeze` so that Flow knows that the values won't change: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51166430/592125