# Defining a Union Type from object values in Flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have an enum like this:

```
const Filter = {
  ALL: 'ALL',
  COMPLETED: 'COMPLETED',
  UNCOMPLETED: 'UNCOMPLETED'
};
```

What I'd like to do is declare a union type like this:

```
type FilterType = Filter.ALL | Filter.COMPLETED | Filter.UNCOMPLETED
```

However, this fails, but I'm not sure why. According to the [Flow docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-sealed-objects):

> When you create an object with its properties, you create a sealed object type in Flow. These sealed objects will know all of the properties you declared them with and the types of their values.

So, if I'm reading that correctly, Flow should be able to create a type from those values. Instead, it fails with:

`Cannot use string as a type because string is a value. To get the type of a value use typeof.`

Here's a link to a [Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAYgSwDZQKYCcCCMC8MDeAUDDJgDJkBcMA5OWTQDTEwDCA8gLIAKZAogBU+AEWo0OPfkOFMWAVQByE3oJFjFyqSJqEAvgG5ChKAE8ADqnjI06AedTY8AEgDSqExAA8piyABmVigYmAB8RqCQsIhB6ABCuDDsAEYAVqjAUAB0fuioqABeqAAURCT0YvSyJJqqorQ10lUwGlwq0upKrVoyegCUhsb2gTZ2FvF40TaxmfQwAD7DGNMNIvOLcZktkrXh4NDrrNROAEqoAIYAJuxgSCaepaQU1NDoCGAA5szVXbXPUK8fL7NTrbdowF5vd56EIJB7lWiVIErOriH6NIFbNpqWiY7o6AxGHyWSYYUaoVgJEnoVgzChrKk05H06wYGm42pAA) with a possible solution (that I'm not happy with) and other approaches that have unsuccessfully worked.

Comment: `type FilterType = 'ALL' | 'COMPLETED' | 'UNCOMPLETED'`...? I mean, if the constants are going to be named the same as their string values, there's no more hard-coding involved than there already is. You could also `const Filter: { [K in FilterType]: K } = { ... }`

Comment: "there's no more hard-coding involved than there already is". There's the chance of typos; I'd prefer to just reference the enum itself.

Comment: You can't do that. As the error says, you're using a _value_ as a _type_. Write your type first, and then implement your type with an object, or you don't even have to write an object at all, just use string literals.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but at the same time not having magic strings floating around is a better pattern. If I needed to change one of the values, I'd just change it in one spot instead of (in this case) two. All this said, I feel like the `$Keys<typeof Filter>` is the "right" way to do this in Flow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an easier solution. You can use [`$Values`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-values) utility to get union of value types. And in order to make flow resolve types as literal types instead of just `string` the object should be frozen:

```
const FilterA = Object.freeze({
  ALL: 'ALL',
  COMPLETED: 'COMPLETED',
  UNCOMPLETED: 'UNCOMPLETED'
});

type FilterTypeA = $Values<typeof FilterA>;


let a: FilterTypeA = FilterA.ALL; //OK
a = 'COMPLETED'; //OK

a = 'foo'; //$Expect error: string is incompatible with enum FilterTypeA
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAYgSwDZQKYCcCCMC8MDyARgFarBQB0AZuqqgF6oAUA3gFAwyYAy3AXDADkPboIA0HGAGF8AWQAK3AKIAVJQBEBgmQuVr14yQFUAcjsWqNW0+b0bBbAL4BKANxs2UAJ4AHVPGQ0dBVfVGw8ABIANQBDJABXVAgAHm8-ECoAlAxMAD53DyRUWBiBRGzg0PCsoMwKEVcYAHom-ABpNhjcIVtLA0aW9o8uvEEqEBBBAaaIpQAPP3IYDHQQdAFodAQwAHMYBAh9sFAAWx8YqARCIpgAdwQoAAtlsHiTmowQv0wgA)

This pattern works since [0.60.0 version](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/Changelog.md#notable-bug-fixes-2)

Comment: Are there any type implications of using Object.freeze or is it just for immutability?

Comment: @JamesKraus Only immutability - in this case flow can be sure that property types can't be changed. As a result `$Values<typeof FilterA>` will be `'ALL' | 'COMPLETED' | 'UNCOMPLETED'` instead of `string`

Comment: Added link to source